# Declarative Rendering Issue

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade

At the core of Vue.js is a system that enables us to declaratively render data to the DOM using straightforward template syntax:

```
<div id="app">
      {{ message }}
</div>

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue!'
  }
})
```

I run this code but I got an error

> Use of undefined constant message - assumed 'message' (this will throw
>   an Error in a future version of PHP)

After hard work, I found out that this forgot @ `@{{ message }}` Can anyone tell me what @ what works in the Laravel Blade template with Vue.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are using `{{ message }}` in your blade. which is interpreted as a php. so you have to use `@` before `{{}}`.

using @ before blade expression will be skipped by blade.

```
<div id="app">
      @{{ message }}
</div>

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue!'
  }
})
```

for more information

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade

Comment: @UdhavSarvaiya I am glad it helped you.